# AMPscript: Including Ordinal Indicators In Date Formatting

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, date, formatting

I have an automated email that will be sent every month and I'm trying to get the expiry to reference the last date of the current month formatted to read *31st January, 2019* or *28th February, 2019*. I'm currently using:

```
%%[ <br/>
SET @firstday=Format(concat(DatePart(Now(),"month"),"/01/",DatePart(Now(),"year")),"MM/dd/yy")<br/> SET @nextmonth = DateAdd(@firstday,"1","M") <br/>
SET @lastday = Format(DateAdd(@nextmonth,"-1","D"),"d MMMM, yyyy") <br/>
]%% <br/>
<br/>

Date: %%=v(@lastday)=%%
```

**Output:**

```
31 August, 2019
```

Is there a way I can get *st* or *th* to sit after the numeric value?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly ideal solution, but could do datepart() to get day month year and then do a conditional to append the correct 'st' or 'th'.

For instance:

```
Set @day = datepart(@endmonthdate, 'D')
Set @month = datepart(@endmonthdate, 'M')
Set @year = datepart(@endmonthdate, 'Y')

If length(@day) > 1 then

  Set @dayend = substring(@day, 2, 1)

Else

  Set @dayend = @day

Endif

If @day == 11 OR @day == 12 OR @day == 13 then

  Set @ append = "th"

ElseIf @dayend == 1 then

  Set @append = "st"

Elseif @dayend == 2 then

  Set @append = "nd"

Elseif @dayend == 3 then

  Set @append = "rd"

Else

  Set @append = "th"

Endif

Set @dayoutput = Concat(@day,@append, ' ',@month,' ',@year))
```

This may not be 100% accurate. I am typing this on my phone in my bed in disney, so may be best to treat it more as pseudo code.